# How to create backup image of clean Windows partition without using dd?

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, dd

I would like to create image of my fresh Windows 7 partition (with drivers and updates only). It occupies 'only' about 35GB of my 250GB partition, so I'm searching for **alternatives to dd** because I would like to have **image thats <40GB**. **Is there any way to do this on Ubuntu?**

I try to run away from Windows solutions to this problem because recovering Windows from MS backup takes me more than 16 hours, where installing new Windows is less than 45min (I'm not counting time that I've spend on OEM spamware removal, up to date drivers installation and OS updates).

Comment: Have you looked at Clonezilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully used partimage to copy a partition and I also know of clonezilla that is very well spoke of and can be ran live as well.

Comment: Thanks, I've used clonezilla, still I have to search for a way to verify my image. Either compression is very good, or it's got corrupted along the way (18GB size from 35GB).